# How to create or define a dictionary in liquid templates?

Tags: json, dictionary, liquid

According to [shopify](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/#emptydrop),
The only possible types of objects that be created are:

- String
- Number
- Boolean
- Nil
- Array
- EmptyDrop

Any workarounds that anyone might be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating a workaround from [github](https://gist.github.com/glaubermagal/397ec4c209068637563f14d3b9edde78), (For more visibility)

**Emulating / Fake dictionary workaround**

Example:

```
Declaring:
{% assign rgbColors = "red:#FF0000,green:#00FF00,blue:#0000FF" | split: "," %}

{% assign value = "green" %}

Acessing:
{% for color in rgbColors %}
    {% assign colorKeyVal = color | split ":" %}
    {% assign colorKey = colorKeyVal[0] %}
    {% assign colorValue = colorKeyVal[1] %}
    {% if colorKey == value %}
        <div style="background: {{ colorValue }}"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```